# call variable from other variable R

Tags: r, list, variables

I'm trying to call a variable from a variable of list name, this is an example:

```
x<-c("a","b")
a<-3
b<-4
```

is there a method to call the variable a from the variable x, for example doing something like x[1]?

thank you

Comment: There is a way, using the function `get`. But there are probably better ways to approach what you're trying to do (see the answer for that).

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly you want to select a variable from a list. Your current method will yield only the character:

```
R> x<-c("a","b")
R> a<-3
R> b<-4
R> x[1]
[1] "a"
```

Instead, try changing your order like this:

```
R> a<-3
R> b<-4
R> x <- c(a,b)
R> x[1]
[1] 3
```